# CSS syntax not working after json code added - VSCode

Tags: html, css, django, syntax

I used these lines of code to get back HTML syntax but now CSS syntax is not working.

```
"files.associations": {
        "**/*.html": "html",
        "**/templates/**/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/**/*": "django-txt",
        "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "django-html": "html",
    },
```

Extensions i have:

- HTML CSS Support

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try installing some visual studio extensions like [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css), as you might need something more than purely editing your json file.